# WPF ComboBox ItemTemplate binding to a string collection

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, combobox

I have a combobox in wpf which is bound to a `List<string>`. All works well, but now for some reason I need to bind to an item template. The XAML for the combo box is

```xml
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Tracks}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTrack}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding **WhatShouldBeHere**}"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

If my data source is a custom collection then binding is easy, I should just  pass the property name from custom collection, but as the binding source is a list of string, what should the binding property be?.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It should be

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
```

which is equivalent to

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=.}"/>
```

See the Remarks section on the [Binding.Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.path.aspx) MSDN page for further details.